# Distinguish source when capturing audio with AudioRecord

Tags: android, audio-recording, audiorecord, android-audiorecord

The AudioRecord class allows recording of phone calls with one of the following options as the recording source:
VOICE_UPLINK: The audio transmitted from your end to the other party. IOW, what you speak into the microphone.
VOICE_DOWNLINK: The audio transmitted from the other party to your end.
VOICE_CALL: VOICE_UPLINK + VOICE_DOWNLINK.

I'd like to build an App that records both VOICE_UPLINK & VOICE_DOWNLINK and *identify the source of the voice*.

1. When using VOICE_CALL as the AudioSource option, the UP/DOWN-LINK streams are bundled together in to the received data buffer which makes it hard to identify the source of the voice.
2. Using two AudioRecords with VOICE_UPLINK & VOICE_DOWNLINK does not work - the second AudioRecord fails to start because the first AudioRecord locks the recording stream.

Is there any creative way to bypass the locking problem presented at case (2), thus enable recording of the VOICE_UPLINK & VOICE_DOWNLINK streams simultaneously and easily identifying the source?